# query with if in cake php 2

Tags: if-statement, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to get data with an if in Cakephp version 2

`$this->Zona->find( 'list', array( 'fields' => array('nombre', 'IF(tiempo_hombre=0, tiempo_mujer, tiempo_hombre ')`

but I get an error

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: and does not show the page

Comment: You seem to have some unclosed brackets, try this:
$this->Zona->find('list', array('fields' => array('nombre', 'IF(tiempo_hombre=0, tiempo_mujer, tiempo_hombre)')));

Comment: this query is longer, just show it partially

Comment: $this->Zona->find( 'list', array('fields' => array('nombre', 'IF(tiempo_hombre=0, tiempo_mujer, tiempo_hombre)'),
             'order' => array(
                  'nombre' => 'asc',
             ),
            
             'conditions' => array(
           
            'YEAR(Zona.agno)' => date('Y'),
            array('Zona.nombre  LIKE' => 'GROUPON%'),
            array('Zona.nombre  LIKE' => 'CUPONATIC%'),
   array('Zona.nombre  LIKE' => '*%'),
   array('Zona.nombre  LIKE' => '2X1%')
             //'Zona.nombre LIKE'=> '%GRATUITO',
            
             )));

Comment: Try looking in your error logs where Cake should be outputting more detail than just 'An Internal Error Has Occurred'.

Comment: I can resolve this, because I put this sentence in a select, I change list to all and work!